# How to do poll(stdin) or select(stdin) when stdin is a windows console?

Tags: c, windows, select, console, blocking

Pursuant to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20428616/how-to-handle-window-events-while-waiting-for-terminal-input), I'm trying to determine if I can read a byte without blocking.

Now, I've got several solutions that work for Unix-like systems, but they all crash and burn when trying to port it to windows, because it simply does not follow the *unix* "everything is a file" motto. On windows, there's no `termios` to flip the terminal into non-canonical mode, `fstat` doesn't tell you anything, and although WSA ostensibly offers `select` and more recently, `poll`, they only work on sockets, not any old file handle, and **NOT** the console "file".

So my only thought from checking through the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is to get the count of input events, peek a copy and iterate through it, counting only KEY_UP typed events. But ... ick?! help? better way? or even a little less abominable?

Comment: No you can't do that on Windows with the Windows console. You might want to check [this Windows console function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I believe that the console input handle will be signaled if and only if there is at least one byte available via ReadFile/ReadConsole.  You can test for this using WaitForSingleObject with a timeout of 0.

Comment: Thanks @HarryJohnston that's a good lead. [This doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687036(v=vs.85).aspx) says it should work for console input.

Comment: @luserdroog: oh, that's where it is - I knew I'd seen it somewhere.  Thanks.  You'll only be able to read one byte per call, of course, but console input is slow anyway so the overhead shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6419955/733077